# How to display the last update of an external data source?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, external-data

Following [these instructions](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Calc/113), I was able to insert external data (from [WorldOMeter](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/)) into one of the sheets of my LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet.

I set the refresh interval to 43200 seconds (12 hours), because WorldOMeter updates once a day, as far as I know. This externally linked sheet is named `WM`.

I then created additional sheets, referring to the data in that first one. So far, so good.

However, I'd like to show, on those additional sheets, the last time the data in `WM` was refreshed. I'm sure, this possible somehow...

I'd also like to be able to *force* a refresh -- even if it hasn't been 12 hours since the last one.

Comment: The update date is in the external data. (World / Countries / United States Last updated: July 17, 2020, 22:57 GMT).

Comment: That does not tell me, when the spreadsheet was last updated, though...

Comment: The date changes every time a refresh is done on the page, meaning that it will tell you when the page request was made.  This would be the last time the data updated in the external import.  So the data at this date time would be the last time the sheet updated.

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to access it from Calc itself...